# Spring RestController + Junit Testing

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I'm playing around with spring-test of springframework. My intention is to test the following POST method in my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project")
public class ProjectController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Project createProject(@RequestBody Project project, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // TODO: create the object, store it in db...
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
    // return the created object - simulate by returning the request.
    return project;
  }
}
```

This is my test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ProjectController.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ProjectControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreationOfANewProjectSucceeds() throws Exception {
        Project project = new Project();
        project.setName("MyName");
        String json = new Gson().toJson(project);

        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/project")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }

}
```

When I execute it I get Status Code 415 instead of 201. What am I missing? A simple GET request works.

Comment: Do you have Jackson or another JSON library (if message converter based on some other) available in classpath so Spring's message converter can convert it?

Comment: I have Gson available. I'll test it with Jackson again. Just saw that when @RequestBody is a String it works so it appears that the conversion won't work

Comment: The annotation @EnableWebMvc was missing on my controller. Now it works. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add annotation `@EnableWebMvc` for `@RestController` to work, this is missing from your code, adding this will solve the issue

Comment: i am getting error at post method . its aksing to create post method what did i miss

Comment: Hey @KIRANKUMARMATAM can you provide more context to it?

Comment: KIRAN KUMAR MATAM You need to import it.
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;